# Sharing project first time from local git repository to remote gerrit repository using egit

Tags: egit, gerrit

I am trying to share project from local git repository to remote gerrit repository using egit.

I followed the following steps:

```
1. Created project and related files.
2. Shared project in local repository.
3. Ignored bin and setting by adding .gitignore file
4. Committed all the changes to local repository
```

Now I wanted to push this project to gerrit:

```
1. Right click on project Team -> Remote -> push to gerrit
```

I am using it over http. I have generated http password for the user, and also given access to user. When user tries to push it say remote rejected. I am unable to find the reason for error.

Also if you can provide some basic guidelines of using egit with gerrit, it would be really useful. Do let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Is there an error message when the push is rejected? Could you try pushing using the command-line Git client?

Comment: Yes the only error message I am getting is Remote rejected. Yet the changes move to server but cannot see them in gerrit. I think I donot have command line interface. I am on windows box.

Comment: Could you try the following? Team > Remote > Push..., select the remote, then select *Add All Branches Spec* and finish the wizard.

Comment: If you can provide me some blog or link, which explains how developer should use gerrit, it will be really helpful

Comment: Checkout the wikimedia website. They use gerrit and have a lot of information on how to use it: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit